# Start java app with oracles java and not openjdk

Tags: java, ubuntu, coredump

I have a small app which crashes if I run it with open-jdk/jre so I would like to run it with oracles Java, how can I force it to run with the original Java? I use ubuntu 12 lts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the default jvm as oracle java.. then try it.

Switching between installed Java versions can be accomplished using the update alternatives command.

To get a list of your installed Java platforms, run the following command from the terminal:

```
      sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This will give you a list output similar to this:

There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java). Selection Path Priority Status ------------------------------------------------------------0 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java

auto mode

1070

1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java 1051 manual mode * 2 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java 1069 manual mode Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:

In this case, the Open JDK 6 version is running. To switch to the Open JDK version 7, you would select option1 at the prompt and press the Enter key.

You will now be running the OpenJDK 7 version. No other changes will be needed to switch your Java versions.

Or to set Oracle jdk do similar

Comment: There is only one alternative in link group java: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

Comment: So I will install oracles java 7 first and than switch, thanks. :)

Comment: Pls add dis as ur answer

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the openjdk and install the Oracle jdk. Take a look here http://m.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html